# Detect this parameter difference in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Following are the ways by which I can declare parameters inside a StoredProcedure.

```
@Doc_Type_Id int
```

and

```
@Doc_Type_ID int=null
```

Second implementation shows that this parameter is optional.

Now I am dynamically detecting parameters using

```
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
```

How can i differentiate between these two types of parameter. ParameterDirection of both is Input only. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can tell the difference. Is there a specific reason you need to?

My main response, is really to see if you actually need to use SqlCommandBuilder to derive the parameters for a stored procedure like this? Reason being, you incur a performance hit due to it having to do a round-trip to the database to get this information.

Comment: yes,I understand that there is a performance hit. I need it because i am maintaining an application. Now i am using SqlHelper.cs from Data access block. I have added this new parameter to storedProcedure and set it to null.If we use normal command and connection objects it would have worked fine.But in this case there is a paramter mismatch because SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd) gets parameter count as 4 and try to assign values to them but already coded functions in DAL have only 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the paramater list by calling:

SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME='yourSPnameHere'

But I think this link can really help you

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/FindDefaultValueSPParams.aspx

I guess it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a SP in SQL SERVER 2005

```
alter PROCEDURE test
(
  @no INT,
  @id INT=0
)
AS 
 BEGIN
  SET @id=5
  PRINT @id
 END
```

Now when i use this query

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME='test'
```

Results are same for both parameters

If i use different query

```
 SELECT
    p.name,    
    pm.parameter_id,
    pm.name AS parameter_name,
    pm.has_default_value,
    pm.default_value
 FROM sys.procedures p
   JOIN sys.parameters pm ON p.object_id = pm.object_id
   JOIN sys.types t ON pm.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
 WHERE p.name = 'test'
```

results are same from

```
pm.has_default_value,
pm.default_value
```

I think even SQL Server doesnot know this difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SET FMTONLY ON`to allow validating the parameter values without modifying data or returning rows. Then execute the procedure once for each parameter while setting its value to `DEFAULT`, and all others to `NULL`. An exception is returned for each non-optional parameter which can be handled by a catch block.

```
CREATE PROC GetContacts(@name int = NULL, @phone int, @email int)
AS RETURN
GO

SET FMTONLY ON
EXEC GetContacts DEFAULT, null, null
EXEC GetContacts null, DEFAULT, null
EXEC GetContacts null, null, DEFAULT
SET FMTONLY OFF
GO

/*
-- Results
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure GetContacts, Line 0
Procedure or function 'GetContacts' expects parameter '@phone', which was not supplied.
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure GetContacts, Line 0
Procedure or function 'GetContacts' expects parameter '@email', which was not supplied.
*/
```